# HashSet eclipse debugger variables

Tags: java, debugging, set, hashset

In `Eclipse debugger variables`'s view , im looking at a`HashSet` and it has a map element which contains a `KeySet` and a `Table` but what puzzles me is that this table contains many null references in it , so i want to know what does table represent and what may cause having these many null references ?

because if those are the values in my HashSet they shouldnt many null references cause its set (Sets do not contain duplicate values)

thanks for any hint .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `null` references are just implementation detail. `HashSet`s are implemented by dividing the elements of the sets into many "buckets" and the `null` references just represent empty buckets. No problem for you.